# Calling of function from client side to server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, client-server

I have completed a Node.js code and it is working fine. However, due to some changes, I will need to put the code under `server.js`

Code under `client.js` to append data into mongodb

```html
var monitoredItem  = the_subscription.monitor({
           nodeId: opcua.resolveNodeId("ns=2000;s=TEST"),
           attributeId: opcua.AttributeIds.Value
       },
       {
           samplingInterval: 100,
           discardOldest: true,
          queueSize: 10
       },
       opcua.read_service.TimestampsToReturn.Both
       );
      console.log("-------------------------------------");
       
     monitoredItem.on("changed",function(dataValue){
   console.log(" New Data Receive = ",dataValue.value.value);
   
   if(dataValue.value.value!='No New Data'){
    var row = JSON.parse(dataValue.value.value);
    if(row[0]!='Machine Unit'){
     var machineUnit = row[0];
     var airTemperature = row[1];
     var waterTemperature = row[2];
     var heatTemperature = row[3];
     var roomTemperature = row[4];
     var date = row[5];
     var time = row[6];

     MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/meiban', function(err, db) {
        
     if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Connected to Database");
        

     var document = {
      
       "machineUnit" : machineUnit,
       "airTemperature" : airTemperature,  
       "waterTemperature" : waterTemperature,
       "heatTemperature" : heatTemperature,
       "roomTemperature" : roomTemperature,
       "date" : date,
       "time" : time
     };
       
      //insert record
     db.collection('meibandb').insert(document, function(err, records) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("A new record added ! ");
     });
     
     
     
     db.close();
    
    });
   
   }
   
   }
   
          
     });
   
    }
 ,
```

Right now, i need to put the code to server side. The code i want to put is attached below.

```html
if(dataValue.value.value!='No New Data'){
    var row = JSON.parse(dataValue.value.value);
    if(row[0]!='Machine Unit'){
     var machineUnit = row[0];
     var airTemperature = row[1];
     var waterTemperature = row[2];
     var heatTemperature = row[3];
     var roomTemperature = row[4];
     var date = row[5];
     var time = row[6];

     MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/meiban', function(err, db) {
        
     if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Connected to Database");
        

     var document = {
      
       "machineUnit" : machineUnit,
       "airTemperature" : airTemperature,  
       "waterTemperature" : waterTemperature,
       "heatTemperature" : heatTemperature,
       "roomTemperature" : roomTemperature,
       "date" : date,
       "time" : time
     };
       
      //insert record
     db.collection('meibandb').insert(document, function(err, records) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("A new record added ! ");
     });
     
     
     
     db.close();
    
    });
```

Comment: Just make an AJAX request from the client, run then code server side when you recieve the request, then send the results back.

Comment: How can i do that? I am weak in javascript and nodejs in general. Would appreciate some help @Carcigenicate

Comment: Do you know what an AJAX request is and how to make one?

Comment: Not sure on the AJAX request, is there any guide @Carcigenicate

Comment: Many. Please google first.